# Sql for loop to include returned values as part of a sql insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to insert rows from another query into a single row that is then inserted into another table.

It works if there is only one row returned. However, if the row count is greater than 1 it fails.

I can't figure out the for loop - indicated with the --** section.

```
declare @cn as int, @i as int
set @cn = 569
declare @dM table(dM varchar(max))
declare @rowNum table (rowNum int)
set @i = 1

insert @rowNum
exec ('select count(*) from table1 where c = ' + @cn)
--select rowNum from @rowNum as NumberRows --return 2 rows

if (select rowNum from @rowNum as NumberRows) > 1
begin
insert @dM
exec ('select d.d + '' '' + o.o + '' '' + d.v as rtM from table1 where c = ' + @countNumber)
--returns 2 rows as rtM so there will be two inserted rows
--going now okay
--going later okay

--**
while (@i <= (select count(*) from @rowNum)) --didn't work
--for each row returned in rtM in need to include as part of the overall insert
insert into table2 (cn, rtM, idate)
select
@cn
,'Message is: ' + (select dM from @dM) + ' - the message.'
cz.idate + ' ' + qw.txt
from table3 as cz
inner join table4 as qw on cz.id = qw.id
where cz.cn = @cn
set @i = @i + 1
--**
end
else
begin
--there is only 1 row returned from rtM so there will be a single inserted row
insert @dM
exec ('select d.d + '' '' + o.o + '' '' + d.v as rtM from table where c = ' + @countNumber)
insert into table2 (cn, rtM, idate)
select
@cn
,'Message is: ' + (select dM from @dM) + ' - the message.'
cz.idate + ' ' + qw.txt
from table3 as cz
inner join table4 as qw on cz.id = qw.id
where cz.cn = @cn
end
```

Comment: not sure what all is wrong.. but you should just make @rowNum an INT and set it equal to your count() from table1.. it all kindof went downhill from there

Comment: the @rowNum is a table where i stored the number of rows found in the dM query.

Comment: i changed the following:    set @i = 0  to set @i = 1. Then I ran the code and got the following on the insert where the dM rows are 2:  Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression

Comment: Why do you have dynamic sql all over the place. You don't need dynamic sql for anything you posted here.

Comment: how do i avoid using the dynamic sql?

Comment: This whole process is just not going to work at all the way you have this written. You are using a subquery as a column. It will never return more than 1 row there. To be honest this process needs to be completely rewritten.

Comment: If you really want some help you should first read this article. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of where dynamic sql just doesn't make sense.

```
INSERT @dM
EXEC ('SELECT d.d + '' '' + o.o + '' '' + d.v AS rtM FROM table1 WHERE c = ' + @countNumber)
```

This can be rewritten without dynamic sql like this.

```
INSERT @dM
SELECT d.d + ' ' + o.o + ' ' + d.v as rtM FROM table1 WHERE c = @countNumber
```

The bigger issue here is your query is simply not going to work here period. Dynamic sql or not this is invalid. You are referencing an object or alias named `d` and another one named `o` but neither of these are in the query.

Comment: oh snap - those are part of the join i forgot to include.

Comment: i removed the dynamic sql; how can i get the loop to go through each row and add into to the insert statement where I'm inserting two rows?

Comment: What loop? There is no loop anywhere in any of the code you have posted. You need to use another join when you do your final selects instead of a subquery as a column.

Comment: in the while loop i'm try to do the insert per the number of rows in @dM as it contains 2 rows and i'd like each value to be part of the insert value so that the insert happens twice. I'm not sure how I would join the two rows as two inserts

Comment: @will2m there is NO loop in your code. You have while loop but it is commented out. Here is the problem. We can't see your screen, we have no idea what your project is, no idea what your table structures look like and no idea what you are trying to do. You need to provide us the details here in order for us to help. See this link. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ Unless you can post something useful there is nothing else I can do here.

Comment: okay so i uncommented the while loop and a couple lines under it i ran (select dm from @dm) then i commented out the insert code and when ran it shows the two rows from the dm table. how would i get each value from the table to be part of the value that is inserted into another table?

Comment: See this link. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ Unless you can post something useful there is nothing else I can do here. There are so many things wrong with your code it is NOT a simple fix.

Comment: I'm attempt to get a value from a table and insert it into as part of a combined value for an insert statement; adding more information to get help isn't allowed

Comment: Well then you are on your own. I can't help you with code when I have no details to work with. It doesn't have to be real data, just something that represents the real problem. Best of luck.

Comment: i figure it out - remove the while loop and used embedded selects